# How to convert Automation element in to UITestControl

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I came across one scenario where I have to identify object using Windows UI automation element.

I want to convert this object back to UITestControl, so that I can use inbuilt methods like waitforcontrol ready etc.

How Can I do this?

regards,

User232482

Comment: How is this unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the UITestControlFactory methods. Use UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement Method (Object, String). You'll have to pass your UIAutomation element in the object parameter and the Technology name(Ex: "UIA") to the String method.More details are available in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrolfactory.fromnativeelement.aspx

Comment: Thanks Rocky , it worked